# C# object to json - how to build object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How would the C# object look, o after serialisation json it looks like this?
Already spent few hours on it and cannot figure out how to have email as variable? there will be only one "prospects" and multiple children.

```
{
    "prospects": {
        "1234": {
            "first_name": "New first name",
            "last_name": "New last name"
        },
        "some@email.com": {
            "first_name": "New first name",
            "last_name": "New last name"
        },
        "some.other@email.com": {
            "first_name": "New first name",
            "last_name": "New last name"
        }
    }
}
```

final result should be

Comment: Are you asking how to build a model which could deserialize the example json, or how to build the model to improve your example json?

Comment: We need much more information here.  What is the context?  What _specifically_ are you struggling with?

Comment: I need a model that after serialisation the output is as described.

Comment: @JaroF I'm not sure how you would construct a model like what you are proposing in your example as each value 1234, some@email.com, some.other@email.com would be property names...I added an answer below which I think would give you a correct serialization

Comment: You can use something like - http://json2csharp.com/ , take a look here https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your "keys" are dynamic.  This means you cannot *hard code* it.  Try this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("prospects")]
    public Dictionary<string, NameModel> Prospects { get; set; }
}

public class NameModel
{
    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

From there you can build your object like this:

```
var model = new RootObject()
{
    Prospects = new Dictionary<string, NameModel>()
    {
        { "1234", new NameModel() { FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "Test" }},
        { "some@email.com", new NameModel() { FirstName = "Sue", LastName = "Test" }},
        { "some.other@email.com", new NameModel() { FirstName = "Frank", LastName = "Test" }},
    }
};
```

Which results in this Json:

```
{
    "prospects": {
        "1234": {
            "firstName": "Sam",
            "lastName": "Test"
        },
        "some@email.com": {
            "firstName": "Sue",
            "lastName": "Test"
        },
        "some.other@email.com": {
            "firstName": "Frank",
            "lastName": "Test"
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZbNmn)